# "binary 'operator+' has too many parameters

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Trying to implement operator overloading using the following code:

```
class Number
{
    T value;
public:
    Number(T v);
    Number();
    Number<T> operator+ (Number<T>&, const Number<T> &);
    T getValue() { return value; };
};


template <typename T>
Number<T>::Number(T val):value(val) { }

template <typename T> 
Number<T> Number<T>::operator+ (Number<T>& lhs, const Number<T> & rhs)  {    
     return lhs.value + rhs.value;
}
```

Trying to emulate similar examples found online, but this attempt generates several compiler errors

- '{' missing function header (old-style format list?)
- binary 'operator +' has too many parameters
- class template "Number" has no member "operator+"

  **`Number<T> Number<T>::operator+ (Number<T>& lhs, const Number<T> & rhs)`**

With all the decisions: whether or not to include "`<T>`"; whether or not to use references for sends and returns; whether or not to use "const" and/or "friend"; and whether or not to use "this", "new" and/or "->"; it's confusing enough to search for outside help :).

Any idea what (many things) I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your consideration

Comment: If you have a compiler error, post the *exact* code you are compiling.  [Here are the errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f049aeca7c58051e) I get when I take your posted code, and attempt to compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting about the **implicit `this` parameter** that are present as the first parameter in a **non-static** member function.

To **solve** your probelm just remove the extra first parameter from `operator+` as shown below:

```
template<typename T>
class Number
{
    T value;
public:
    Number(T v);
    Number();
    Number<T> operator+ (const Number<T> &);//REMOVED UNNECESSARY PARAMETER
    T getValue() { return value; };
};



template <typename T>
Number<T>::Number(T val):value(val) { }

template <typename T> 
Number<T> Number<T>::operator+ (const Number<T> & rhs)  {  //REMOVED UNNECESSARY PARAMETER  
     return value + rhs.value;//CHANGED lhs.value to value
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U7bnyIzC2cwBf5Pu).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
Number<T> operator+ (Number<T>&, const Number<T> &);
```

and define operator+ out of the class body this way:

```
template<typename T>
Number<T> operator+(Number<T> const& lhs, Number<T> const& rhs) {
    auto ret{ lhs };
    ret.value += rhs.value;
    return ret;
}
```